# computed properties concatenate two values instead of adding

Tags: knockout.js

I am using computed properties of knockoutjs. here is my `ViewModel`

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this; 
    self.firstValue = ko.observable(6);
    self.secondValue = ko.observable(5);
    self.addValue = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.firstValue() + self.secondValue();
    });
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

and my html binding is as follows :

```
<p><input data-bind="value: firstValue"></p>

<p><input data-bind="value: secondValue"></p>

<p><input data-bind="value: addValue"></p>
```

the problem i am facing that first time its shows 11 that is OK but when i change any value in text box then its concatenating the values instead of showing addition of them . Does i need to use `parseInt` of js when adding properties or i am missing some thing in knockout.js ?

and here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/XwpAY/)

Comment: You need to use `intParse` in your computed.

Comment: Is it not possible to make observable as numerice so always they can be used for numeric opearations ?

Comment: Not out of the box. But you can use extenders: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html#live_example_1_forcing_input_to_be_numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it not possible to make observable as numerice so always they can
>   be used for numeric opearations ?

you can extend the observable like

```
ko.extenders.number = function(observable, opt) {
   return ko.computed({
       read: observable,
       write: function(value) {
           if(typeof value !== "number") {
               value = parseFloat(value);
           }           

           if(!isNaN(value)) {
               observable(value);
           }           
       }
   });
}
```

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Rv7EP/